# Incluir autenticação smtp

Tags: php, smtp

Meu site não está enviando emails quando coloco no servidor do cliente, mas no meu ele envia corretamente(uso o HOO.ST), no servidor do cliente, mostra está mensagem `Servidor de e-mails de saída: grupomenegalli.com.br (o servidor requer autenticação)` e também apresenta isso `Protocolos de e-mail de saída suportados: SMTP`. Acho que eu vou ter usar uma autenticação SMTP

Tem algum modo de apenas incluir uma autenticação no meu php?

PHP:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo json_encode(array('error'=>'true'));
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = ($_POST['subject'] ? $_POST['subject'] : "Website Contact   Form:  $name");



// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'email@to.com.br';// Add your email address inbetween the ''  replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = $subject;
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website   contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nLast Name:     $lastname\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone:  $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
echo json_encode(array('success'=>'true'));
return true;            
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi muito bem sua dúvida, mas me parece que você envia normalmente via localhost (servidor local) mas quando tenta enviar com um servidor externo (do seu cliente) retorna erro de autenticação SMTP, caso seja isso, verifique o usuário, senha, porta, e host do script referente ao seu cliente, caso queira fazer um envio via SMTP externo você precisará definir esses valores em seu script, veja esse exemplo com um smtp do criarsiteweb.net:

```
<?php
 $from = "Seu nome <nome@remetente.com>";
 $to = "Destinatario <destinatario@site,com>";
 $subject = "Assunto";
 $body = "Conteúdo";

 $host = "criarsiteweb.net";
 $port = "587";
 $username = "usuário_smtp";
 $password = "senha_smtp";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Mensagem enviada!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Se você não quiser utilizar usuário e senha você vai precisar configurar o ip do servidor como autorizado no SMTP de envios, NÃO ATIVE A AUTENTICAÇÃO ANÔMICA, faça apenas a autorização do ip do seu host caso queira dispensar o usuário e senha, certifique-se de adaptar seu código para conexão SMTP ou se preferir poderá utilizar uma função phpmail com sendmail diretamente no servidor local (localhost)